# SIP Makefile fail (gnuwin and mingw)

Tags: python-2.7, makefile, mingw, python-sip, gnuwin32

I have downloaded the Sip module for python 2.7, created a makefile and  tried the `make` command on the directory with the makefile, but I get this error:

```
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make[10]: *** [all] Error 2
mingw32-make[10]: Leaving directory 'D:/Users/myLogin/Downloads/python/sip-4.14.5'
```

I get this error with both Gnuwin and mingw32. So I'm at a loss at what to do now. Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use `python configure.py`, the generated `Makefile`s are actually `nmake` makefiles. `nmake` is Microsoft's equivalent to `make`. You can run it by invoking `nmake` in a Visual Studio command prompt, if you have that installed.

For building with `mingw`, you have to indicate that you want to use that particular platform when creating the makefiles, as follows:

```
python configure.py --platform win32-g++
```

After that, invoking `make` works fine.

---

A few details about what happens to you when running `make` on the `nmake` makefile. The generated `nmake` file starts with the following lines:

```
all:
    cd sipgen
    $(MAKE)
    @cd ..
    cd siplib
    $(MAKE)
    @cd ..
```

Because each command on each line is executed in a new shell, the result of `cd sipgen` is actually void. Then, `make` is invoked again, in the current directory -- this results in an infinite recursive loop of `make` invocations. The `[10]` in your error message indicates that it was at the 10th level of recursion. I guess that was the moment that you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> :-)

Comment: tried nmake and it worked! thnks a lot, and thanks for the in-depth explanation. This was the first i ever heard of makefiles, so that really helped :)