# Building the SIP (PyQt) on Windows

Tags: makefile, pyqt, python-sip

In attempt to build [sip](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download) from source packages, I have the infinite loop on a [building](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html#building) step. I run make.exe and it takes the following steps unitl I press Ctrl+Brake:

```
cd sipgen
make
make[1]: Entering directory `C:/sip'
cd sipgen
make
make[2]: Entering directory `C:/sip'
cd sipgen
make
make[3]: Entering directory `C:/sip'
cd sipgen
make
make[4]: Entering directory `C:/sip'
...........................................
cd sipgen
make
make[n]: Entering directory `C:/sip'
^C
```

Makefile in root directory contains code below:

```
all:
    cd sipgen
    $(MAKE)
    @cd ..
    cd siplib
    $(MAKE)
    @cd ..

install:
    cd sipgen
    $(MAKE) install
    @cd ..
    cd siplib
    $(MAKE) install
    @cd ..
    @if not exist C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages mkdir C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages
    copy /y sipconfig.py C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\sipconfig.py
    copy /y C:\sip\sipdistutils.py C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\sipdistutils.py

clean:
    cd sipgen
    $(MAKE) clean
    @cd ..
    cd siplib
    $(MAKE) clean
    @cd ..
```

Do you know the reasons?
Can I solve this issue, or it impossible on Windows?

PS. Sorry for my awful English

Comment: I downloaded sip-4.16.4-snapshot-c2cfa151229a.zip, then from cmd execute : python configure.py then execute make , building is ok .. but the make file contains the following in (all) section :      all:
 @(cd sipgen; $(MAKE))
 @(cd siplib; $(MAKE))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just copy the answer of another question

> If you use python configure.py, the generated Makefiles are actually nmake makefiles. nmake is Microsoft's equivalent to make. You can run it by invoking nmake in a Visual Studio command prompt, if you have that installed.
>
> For building with mingw, you have to indicate that you want to use that particular platform when creating the makefiles, as follows:
>
> ```
> python configure.py --platform win32-g++
> ```
>
> After that, invoking make works fine.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16051239

Answer (score 2):

If you use the PyQt windows installer the sip package will be installed too!

Comment: which PyQt windows installer will install the SIP package as well? On this site (http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) it notes that SIP must first be installed.

Comment: It's true I can see the note too. I stopped working with PyQt a while ago and I don't remember how I set up my environment. But I am pretty sure I never installed SIP on my own. Maybe you could check Python install. BTW if you can use PyQt5 I could be better for you in the future :).

Comment: @user25976 That page states _"Before you can build PyQt4 you must have already built and installed SIP"_, but if you install a precompiled version then you don't have to build (I think). There's a sip.exe (version 4.16.4) in my PyQt4 directory (and v4.16.6 in PyQt5) after install, but I don't know whether it's in path afterwards.

Comment: I should change my opinion, sipconfig.py was still missing so I needed to install sip.